# How do i move a data that have same header into the same column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a csv file like this :

```
id | name | phonenumber | id | name | phonenumber |
---------------------------------------------------
01 | name1| 9999222222  | 02 | name2| 39393939399 |
---------------------------------------------------
03 | name3| 2149999222  | 04 | name4| 29491294192 |
---------------------------------------------------
```

how can i change it into like this :

```
id | name | phonenumber |
-------------------------
01 | name1| 9999222222  |
-------------------------
02 | name2| 39393939399 |
-------------------------
03 | name3| 2149999222  |
-------------------------
04 | name4| 29491294192 |
-------------------------
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need reshape it

```
df=pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape((-1,3)),columns=df.columns[:3])
df
Out[256]: 
  id    name        phone
0  1   name1   9999222222
1  2   name2  39393939399
2  3   name3   2149999222
3  4   name4  29491294192
```

Comment: (lambda c: pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(c, map(np.ravel, map(df.get, c))))))({*df})